# <uses-permission> tag appears after <application> tag

Tags: java, android

im having a problem which is saying  tag appears after  tag
and the error is showing in this line 
this is my mainfest.xml i hope you can help me and thanks in advance :D

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="imamalsajadsayings.android.com" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity 
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity
            android:name="imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: If thats the error, move the `<uses-permission>` tags above `<application>`. Thats what it is telling you to do.

Answer (score 27):

it should be like this

Put your user-permission tag just below the user-sdk and above the application tag

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.test.app"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activityandroid:name="com.test.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Sorry to revive this thread but, why the hell does android-studio say to put it after the <application> tag, even when we have it after the tag, it only stops doing that when we have it before like you said, it makes no sence.

Comment: @MrSanchez I also found this and going through the lint description, I found out `Incorrect order of elements in manifest  The <application> tag should appear after the elements which declare which version you need, which features you need, which libraries you need, and so on. In the past there have been subtle bugs (such as themes not getting applied correctly) when the <application> tag appears before some of these other elements, so it's best to order your manifest in the logical dependency order.`

Answer (score 0):

Use this above  tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be put in front of , then the problem can be solved.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
</application>
```

Answer (score -2):

Fundamentally all your uses-permission tags must reside NEVER in the application tag as you have currently in your xml. Please change your XML lines to look like below:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: But his uses-permission tags are NOT in the application tag.